Flutter Android/Gradle setting
I am not using flutter on a daily basis but was always interested in writing apps with flutter. However, every time I come back to it or I follow along a tutorial I have a lot of updating and migrating to do which is super frustraiting...
With all these versions and places to add them it feels like I will never get a feeling of how things work there.
How do you stay on track with all these changes?
How have you learned what to add to all these build files?
Do you have material that helps?
I was already checking lots of migration pages. Running directly into the next problem ...

In general terms, when you generate a Flutter app with flutter create command, all those native configurations are done automatically based on the Flutter version you have installed. Sometimes, If you have an older Flutter version those config files may be outdated, but in most cases the error in terminal will tell you how to fix them.
That's it in terms of a basic flutter app, it is really very easy if you have basic flutter requirements in your computer.

Thank you very much! With flutter create I won´t run into problems for sure. But still I don´t know what I can configure / should configure in all these files. I think it is poorly described and my biggest problem is following along tutorials which were created with very old flutter versions. I am not able to get them running (or it takes an hour)... :/

those files should not be touched if you don't need to, they are usually to work in Android/Ios/Web/desktop devices. In most cases you will use them is because you need an external package that requires them (usually because they need native permission or access to camera, storage, etc), and they explain how to do it in their documentation
